# Laravel Schedule - Azure App service on linux

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

I have a issue with my scheduler. The app is on azure (app service on linux)

I've created a startup.sh that is executed everytime the app starts

```
 #!/bin/bash    
 apt-get update -qq && apt-get install cron -yqq
 mkdir /home/LogFiles/cronjob
 (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan schedule:run >> /home/LogFiles/cronjob/cronjobresult.log 2>&1")|crontab
 service cron start
```

I can see in the logs that the two commands that were supposed to be executed at midnight have ran:

```
[2022-05-24T00:00:04+08:00] Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' send:emails > '/dev/null' 2>&1
[2022-05-24T00:00:09+08:00] Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' publish:articles > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

However, it did not work because the emails have not been sent and the database has not been updated. If I connect to azure with SSH and run the commands manually from the console, eveything works perfectly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you SSHing in as the same user account you're running `crontab` as?

Comment: Good question, I didn't think about that. I'll have a look and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Did you check the Laravel logs to see if you got any error back? (do not confuse with the crontab logs)

Comment: @matiaslauriti no error in the logs

Comment: @sheng Using SSH, I'm the root user. The crontab has been created through the startup.sh file. I can't find a command to check which user is running the crontab tho.

Comment: You can use `crontab -l`, and if it says "empty" you can try `crontab -u USER -l` and try using different `users`, `root` too. The one that shows the crontab is the one running it

Comment: Both commands ```crontab -l``` and ```crontab -u root -l``` return the crontab added by startup.sh  ```* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan schedule:run >> /home/LogFiles/cronjob/cronjobresult.log 2>&1```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is still relevant but maybe for future reference. We ran into the same problem. We found it to be related to the environment. When running the commands from cron the environment variables were not loaded. This can be solved by adding `. /etc/profile` in the scheduled command. So the startup.sh script becomes:

```
 #!/bin/bash    
 apt-get update -qq && apt-get install cron -yqq
 mkdir /home/LogFiles/cronjob
 (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * . /etc/profile && /usr/local/bin/php /home/site/wwwroot/artisan schedule:run >> /home/LogFiles/cronjob/cronjobresult.log 2>&1")|crontab
 service cron start
```